# Can I use `DllReferencePlugin` with `webpack-dev-server`?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

How to inject my `dll.bundle.js` to `index.html` file?

In chrome console, it throws an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: vendor is not defined`and`Uncaught TypeError: **webpack_require**(...) is not a function error.

It's because of my `Dll` does not inject to `index.html` file

I don't want to use express or node server to host my static file. I just want to use `webpack-dev-server`. How can I do that with `Dll` bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your DLL bundle is generally built in Webpack as well, as the documentation [explains](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/dll-plugin/#usage):

[image: Image showing DllRererencePlugin Usage from Webpack Docs]

You are ultimately responsible for providing the file. You could simply inline it in your index.html as an inline script: `<script> //paste file here contents here </script>`.

Otherwise it is pretty typical to let express serve the files statically in development (CDN in production). [This stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48745775/how-to-use-webpack-dll-plugin) provides a good example of usage/setup.