# How to use webpack DLL Plugin?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2, webpack-3

I am just starting to use webpack 3 and dllplugin. I managed to find a few blog articles abt. this. However none of them with a proper code sample/ GitHub samplecode. Does anyone know any references to sample code for this/ working example?

Comment: https://medium.com/@emilycoco/how-to-use-the-dll-plugin-to-speed-up-your-webpack-build-dbf330d3b13c

Answer (score 5):

This is a good simple example:

We define our functions in vendor.js (this is the library that we are going to reference as DLL).

**vendor.js**

```
function square(n) {
  return n*n;
}

module.exports = square;
```

Then define WebPack configuration to export this as a DLL using DllPlugin.

**vendor.webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    vendor: ['./vendor'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'vendor.bundle.js',
    path: 'build/',
    library: 'vendor_lib',
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.DllPlugin({
    name: 'vendor_lib',
    path: 'build/vendor-manifest.json',
  })]
};
```

In our application, we simply reference the created DLL using require(./dllname)

**app.js**

```
var square = require('./vendor');
console.log(square(7));
```

And in WebPack build configuration, we use DllReferencePlugin to reference the created DLL.

**app.webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: ['./app'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'app.bundle.js',
    path: 'build/',
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
    context: '.',
    manifest: require('./build/vendor-manifest.json'),
  })]
};
```

Finally, we need to compile the DLL, and then the application using WebPack.

**Compile with:**

```
webpack --config vendor.webpack.config.js
webpack --config app.webpack.config.js
```

To include the file inside HTML, use simple JS include script tag.

**Use with the following index.html**

```
<script src="build/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="build/app.bundle.js"></script>
```

Reference: https://gist.github.com/robertknight/058a194f45e77ff95fcd
Also you can find more DLL examples in WebPack repository:
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples

Comment: In your app.js, why you `require('./vendor')`? Shouldn't you `require('./vendor.bundle.js')`?

Comment: @PunCha you need to reference source files in your source code (.js). bundle file is the output and will be generated by the tool

Comment: what's the meaning of `vendor_lib` in `vendor.webpack.config.js`?they don't appear in `app.webpack.config.js` and `app.js` and `index.html`

Comment: @tcpiper vendor_lib here is the name of the library. app.js uses require to include vendor.js